# Translating VB to PHP - Floating point issues

Tags: php, vba, math

I'm attempting to translate my VB code into PHP, and am having issues with floating point numbers. VB seems to round a particular number while PHP doesn't.

I have multiple equations like these so need a solution which will adequately calculate them all as the exact number as VB calculates.

Is there any reason why this is occurring?

**PHP**

```
483.737 + 105678 / 293.6700134 = 843.58987968799
```

**VBA (Excel):**

```
483.737 + 105678 / 293.6700134 = 843.5898797
```

With ini_set('precision', 10)

PHP

[image]

VBA

[image]

Comment: _"VB (Excel)"_ Are you using VB.NET or VBA? And how _exactly_ are you calculating this (in code)?

Comment: VBA - apologies.
In VBA its displayed through an excel spreadsheet - i'm just debugging the LARGE equation for the moment.

On PHP i'm using die(insert equation here) to debug it.

Comment: When dealing with floating point numbers, whenever you inspect them you ultimately deal with a “to string” somewhere, and that conversion, from a well-defined mathematical concept or international standard, tends to break things more often than not. Your numbers look identical to me, although one goes to greater precision, but once again, that is a display thing.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas - this may be the case Feel free to post as answer and ill tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with floating point numbers, whenever you inspect them you ultimately deal with a “to string” somewhere, and that conversion, from a well-defined mathematical concept or international standard, tends to break things more often than not. If the math checks out, but things look weird while debugging, that is probably the case. I don't specifically know if VBA and PHP store their floating point numbers in the same way, however, so it is possible that some math could be off.

Your numbers look identical to me, although one goes to greater precision, but once again, that is a display thing.